# Androidアプリ開発において、ListViewとTextViewをLinearLayoutで並べたい。

Tags: android, java, xml

Androidアプリ開発において、ListViewとTextViewをLinearLayoutで並べたい。
AndroidStudioでNavigation　Drawerを用いたアプリ開発を行っていて、
左から出てくるメニューのカスタマイズを行いたくて、
上にTextViewで文字（見出し）を表示、下にListViewでリストを表示というのをやるために、
**fragment_navigation_drawer.xml**ファイル内に

[image: fragment_navigation_drawer.xml]

と書いたのですが、文字は表示されて、リストの方の文字は表示されませんでした。（場所の確保はされている）
ListViewだけ抜き出して書くとちゃんと文字も表示されていて、LinearLayoutの中に入れてしまうと表示されなくなります。
どうすればリストが表示されるか分からないので、どなたか教えていただけると嬉しいです。

---

`activity_main.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.yuriyuri.toolbar.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

`listlayout.xml`

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/text1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:textColor="#282828"
  android:paddingLeft="6dip"
  android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
/>
```

`color.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fdc6ce">
            </solid>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#44F08000">
            </solid>
            <stroke android:color="#fdc6ce" android:width="2dp">
            </stroke>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

'ListAdapterの実装部'

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            R.layout.listlayout,
            android.R.id.text1,
            //android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
            }));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

Comment: `layout_height=0px`は意図的な記述で、`weightSum=5`として割合で表示させたいということでしょうか？

Comment: はい！TextViewはListViewよりも縦に小さく表示されてほしかったので、1:4の割合で設定しました。
verticalでlayout_weightを設定する場合は、layout_heightを両方とも0pxにするという決まりがあったと思い、そのように記述しました。

Comment: その方法で問題ないはず。提示されている情報では、`android:listSelector`に`@layout/color`を指定しているところが気になります（StateDrawableやColorList以外を指定すると、実行時に落ちるような）。あとは`ListAdapter`を設定しているコード部分がどうなっているかでしょうか。

Comment: 質問はいつでも再編集することができます。`color.xml`は`res/drawable`に置いた方が良いと思うのですが、それは本題ではなさそうです。`ArrayAdapter`に渡している`R.layout.listlayout`に`android.R.id.text1`の`id`を持つ`TextView`がないです（`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`に置き換えてみてください）。また、`listl‌​ayout.xml`の`ListView`に`id`がないのですが、`mDrawerListView`として取得しているのでしょうか？それとも`mDrawerListView`とは別のもの（`ListView`のセルとして`ListView`を表示したい？）のでしょうか？

Comment: 大変申し訳ありません。私の確認不足で、xmlファイルの名前を間違って伝えてました。質問で書いたのはfragment_navigation_drawer.xmlで、listlayout.xmlではTextViewにちゃんとtext1とidの指定がありました。投稿直したのでお手数かけますが見ていただけると嬉しいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mDrawerListView`は以下のように取得しています。

```
mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
               R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
```

`inflater.inflate()`がレイアウトのルート要素を返しますので、テンプレートの**fragment_navigation_drawer.xml**の場合は、ルート要素である`ListView`をそのままキャストして利用することができるのです。

そこに階層を追加して`TextView`を追加したい場合、`inflater.inflate()`で返却されるものもルート要素である`LinearLayout`になってしまいますので、その対応をする必要があります。

まず、**fragment_navigation_drawer.xml**の`ListView`に適当な`id`を付与します。

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/title"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView" <!-- idで名前を付ける -->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

あとは、`onCreateView()`でリストビューを取得する処理を、以下のように修正します。

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ルート要素はLinearLayoutになっている
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    // そこからレイアウトで付けた"listView"という名前でリストビューを取得する
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            R.layout.listlayout,
            android.R.id.text1,
            //android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
            }));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。すごく分かりやすくて理解できました！
ただ、そのようにコードを書き換えるとエラーで、
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`
と出てきて、強制終了してしまいました。調べたところ、１つのActivityに複数のViewを設定していると書いてありました。ですが、変更した点はリストビューを取得する方法で、Activityにセットはしてないと思い、また悩んでます。

Comment: 再確認できるのは夜になりそうですが、`return mDrawerListView;`をここでは`return view`に変えるのが抜けてました、すみません。

Comment: 修正したコードではどうでしょうか？

Comment: 修正していただいたコードを書いたら無事テキストビューも表示されました！！コードもすごく分かりやすくて、本当に感謝でいっぱいです。ありがとうございます！！